# Why are both of these forms of the CHSH inequality correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality

Most of the time, when looking up the CHSH inequality, I find something like
$$E(0,0)+E(0,1)+E(1,0)-E(1,1)\leq 2.$$

But other times I find something along the lines of 
$$\vert E(0,0)+E(0,1)\vert+\vert E(1,0)-E(1,1)\vert\leq2.$$

(Take a look at pages 12 and 13 of [this link](https://physics.usyd.edu.au/quantum/Coogee2011/Presentations/Browne.pdf) (the presentation "Bell inequalities made simple(r)", by Dan Browne) for examples of both forms.)

These seem like very different equations to me, but apparently they're not.

Edited bonus question:
How come $\vert a+b+c-d \vert=\vert a+b \vert + \vert c - d \vert$?

Comment: How to you infer the equality you give in the "bonus question" from those two inequalities?  --  Would you, e.g., also claim that 2<=3 and 1<=3 implies 2=1?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I agree that $\vert a+b+c-d \vert=\vert a+b \vert + \vert c - d \vert$ is untrue. My question is how come it is the case that, after fixing the first equation to be $\vert E(0,0)+E(0,1)+E(1,0)-E(1,1) \vert\leq 2$, the first equation is the same as $\vert E(0,0)+E(0,1)\vert+\vert E(1,0)-E(1,1)\vert\leq2$. Which certainly implies $\vert a+b+c-d \vert=\vert a+b \vert + \vert c - d \vert$ even though it is, logic wise, false.

Comment: I don't see why it would imply it.  (Even though, in *this specific context*, it might be true.)  --  Do you know how CHSH is derived?  If not, look at it, e.g. in Preskill's lecture notes.

Comment: Ah yes, so it's true for this particular system and not so much a mathematical truth that holds for every system. It's what I suspected, but I am glad I checked it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

The derivation of the CHSH inequality actually gives
$$
 -2\leq E(0,0)+E(0,1)+E(1,0)-E(1,1)\leq 2.
\tag{1}
$$
This can also be written
$$
 \Big|E(0,0)+E(0,1)+E(1,0)-E(1,1)\Big|\leq 2.
\tag{2}
$$
The arguments of $E(\cdots)$ are just labels indicating two different measurable properties, so other inequalities may be obtained by permuting the labels. Permute the labels $0\leftrightarrow 1$ in the second argument of $E(\cdots)$ to get
$$
 \Big|E(0,1)+E(0,0)+E(1,1)-E(1,0)\Big|\leq 2.
\tag{3}
$$
The pair of inequalities
$$
 |a+b|\leq 2
 \hskip2cm
 |a-b|\leq 2
\tag{4}
$$
is equivalent to the single inequality
$$
 |a|+|b|\leq 2.
\tag{5}
$$
To see that (4) implies (5), first consider the case where $a$ and $b$ have the same sign (and then it's obvious), and then consider the case where $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs (and then it's obvious again). Now set
$$
 a = E(0,0)+E(0,1)
\hskip2cm
 b = E(1,0)-E(1,1)
$$
so that the first and second equations in (4) are equations (2) and (3), respectively, and equation (5) is
$$
 \Big|E(0,0)+E(0,1)\Big|+\Big|E(1,0)-E(1,1)\Big|\leq 2.
\tag{6}
$$

Comment: Of course all of the numbered statements in this answer should be called "inequalities," not "equations." (Fixing this now would have bumped the post up to the home page again, so I left it as is, since there's no real risk of confusion.)

Answer (score 2):

The provided presentation relies on two sources, Cirelson B. S. (1980) (in this paper, their name is incorrectly transliterated from Цирельсон to Cirelson instead of Tsirelson) and Popescu S., *et. al.* (1994). Both of these only support the absolute version, but one of them uses an alternate notation with two inequalities.

Cirelson B. S. (1980) uses the normal version:
[image]
(picture contains the CHSH equation with absolute marks)

Popescu S., *et. al.* (1994) uses the double-inequality version:
[image]
(picture contains the CHSH equation without absolute marks, but with another inequality sign showing it needs to be higher than -2.)

It is likely that the provided presentation has incompletely reproduced the second, leaving out the first inequality. Either way, the first inequality on slide 13 in the provided presentation is incomplete based on these sources.

Comment: So how come, if I interpret it correctly, is it that $\vert a+b+c-d \vert=\vert a+b \vert + \vert c - d \vert$?

Comment: @Jenessa There is nothing incorrect about reproducing only the right part of the inequality.  If -2<=x<=2, then x<=2 follows from it.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Although that is a correct assertion and I changed 'incorrect' to 'incomplete', it is incorrect in the sense of not including all bounds set by the CHSH inequality.

Comment: @Jenessa Thanks for the help and also greetings for Eindhoven ;-). I can't, however, decipher the comment you made earlier. My guess is that you state that $\vert a+b+c-d \vert=\vert a+b \vert + \vert c - d \vert$ is only true for certain cases, but that's about the extent of how far I got. I am unsure now about how, after fixing the first equation, $\vert E(0,0)+E(0,1)+E(1,0)-E(1,1) \vert\leq 2$ is the same as $\vert E(0,0)+E(0,1)\vert+\vert E(1,0)-E(1,1)\vert\leq2.$ in case there was any confusion. :-)

Comment: @Jenessa True; but still the version with only <=2 is a Bell inequality (in the sense that it is satisfied classically but can be violated quantumly), which - I guess - is the statement to be made in the talk.

Comment: @Jenessa So what you're saying is that both equations are true only for this particular system and so it's not so much a mathematical truth?

Comment: It's what I thought but I thank you for all your help. My gratitude. :-)

Comment: Chiral Anomaly's answer contains a much better explanation of the math

Comment: @Jenessa : An aside on the “incorrect” transliteration of  Цирельсон : It’s not incorrect, since it is conformant with e.g. Soviet transliteration scheme of that era like [GOST 16876-71](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_16876-71). It is at most obsolete, but I’m not even sure of that. Similarly, Holevo and Kholevo are the same (brillant) scientist